# Oracle SQL decimal precision on Select

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello i have a database column called price and the data in it is .1

I want to select this column using a select query and return it back to the application with 0.10. Is this possible to do this when selecting the column?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to return a number to the application?  Or a string?

If you want to return a number, you don't care about the formatting.

If you want to return a string, you can use the `TO_CHAR` function with the format mask 'fm0.00'

```
  1* select to_char( .1, 'fm0.00' ) from dual
SQL> /

TO_CH
-----
0.10
```

Comment: the issue here is the data in to column has all different values. For example, here are a few -> 0.1 .1 .10 5.00 45 999.1 999.00. We do want it as a string format. Is there a way to cover all formats with one command? thanks!

Comment: @ScootaP - Is the column itself a NUMBER?  Or a VARCHAR2?  If you are stating that the column has both 0.1 and .1, that would imply that it's a VARCHAR2.  I was assuming that the column was a NUMBER.  What string would you want returned for each value?  Do you always want two digits of precision and a leading 0 if the number is less than 1?  That's what my query does.  If you want something else, you'll need to explain exactly what you want.

Comment: I see that your query satisfies what i need. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

SELECT TO_CHAR(column, '0.99')
FROM   table